# numbers outputting incorrectly C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I wrote this code, and i need some help!

as you can see from pictures below, i'm having difficulties figuring out how to fix this issues. 
i'm submitting my code and the results are as follows

pictures are in the links:

for the first picture i wanna fix the "12" issue.

![pic1](https://ibb.co/femboG

for second picture i wanna fix it as if there is no valid numbers to output "An average cannot be calculated" instead

![pic2](https://ibb.co/bJ0moG

for last picture i need to fix the -0.00 issue

![pic3](https://ibb.co/nE7oiG

Thats all

.

Compile command:

g++ lesson7part2.cpp -Wall -Wextra -Wuninitialized -pedantic-errors -Wconversion -o a.out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   ofstream outFile;
   string outFileName = "invalid-numbers.txt";


char filename[]="";

cin>>filename;


ifstream in(filename);


    if (!in.good())

{

cout<<"File " << "\""<< filename <<"\"" << " could not be opened" <<endl;
exit(0);
}

   outFile.open(outFileName.c_str()); //open file
   if (!outFile) { //check if u opened file properly or not
   cout << "Error opening " << outFileName << " " << endl;
   return 1;

   }

   double inNumber = 0;
   double valTotal = 0;
   double countValNum = 0;
   double count =0;
   while (in >> inNumber) {

       if (inNumber >= 0 && inNumber <= 110) {
           valTotal += inNumber;
           countValNum++;
       } else {
           outFile << inNumber << fixed << setprecision(2) << endl;
       }
       count++;
   }
   cout << "Reading from file " << "\""<< filename <<"\"" << endl;
   cout << "Total values: " << count << endl;
   cout << "Invalid values: " << (count - countValNum) << endl;
   cout << "Valid values: " << countValNum << endl;
   cout << "Average of valid values: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << (valTotal / countValNum) << endl;

outFile.close();
in.close();

   return 0;

}
```

HERE:

so as u see in pictures I need to fix the numbers to sisplay correctly not sure how to fix that myself.

. . 
 . . 
 THIS IS EXAMPLE ON HOW ITS SUPPOSED TO LOOK LIKE

Here is an example of a working program:

Assume the file name read in from cin is:

input.txt

and that input.txt contains:

-12

0

98.5

100

105.5

93.5

88

75

-3

111

89

-12

Your program would output the following:

Reading from file "input.txt"

Total values: 12

Invalid values: 4

Valid values: 8

Average of valid values: 81.19

The contents written out to file invalid-numbers.txt (if they are less than 0 ) are:

-12

-3

111

-12

Comment: Use std::string instead of char arrays. `char filename[]="";` how long could the read filname be?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read into a single element array here:

```
char filename[]="";

cin>>filename;
```

This will corrupt your memory. You need to allocate some size to the filename string. For instance:

```
char filename[256] = "";
```

will do the job for filenanes that are at most 256 characters long.

Putting that aside, the char[] is a C construct. You are using C++, so you should also do things the C++ way. Instead of simple array use the C++ strings or stringstreams. It will make your work much easier.

```
std::string filename{};
cin >> filename;
```